# Word Caps-Lock click will return to the other language

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, language, capslock

I want to write in 2 languages in Word Office.
I'm in my language and click Caps-Lock to swtich to English.
When I click again on Caps-Lock in order to return to my language, it stays in english(low letters).

How can I make it return to my language right after clicking again on Caps-Lock?

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Word is in question, and what OS are you using?  Language change bound to the Caps Lock key is not a normal/default function, how did you set that up in the first place?

Comment: I have Word 2010. Windows 7.
For example, when I click Caps-Lock in notepad, and click it again, the language changes to myn. That's not happening in Word.
What option taking care of this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a US keyboard?  I know, for instance, that the Japanese keyboard switches between English and Japanese if you hit caps lock.  If you actually want caps lock, you need to press shift-caps lock.  Your keyboard may be similar.